# Wrong encoding with mail function of php in mail client(The Bat!)

Tags: php, email

I had a issue today that I spend for 2 hours. I used simple mail function, and it worked ok in gmail but in the bat! there were wrong encoding with russian letters.

```
if (isset($_POST['var'])) // condition that runs mail 
{
    mail("email@gmail.com", "Subject", "Message");// This works fine on gmail
    //mail("bat@mailservice.ru","Subject","Message");// Wrong encoding
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mail()`. it's braindead simple garbage. Use a proper mailer package, like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, where you can do proper MIME-formatted emails and easily specify charsets.

Comment: Well in my case mail function works fine. I don't need to attach files or smth like that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that mail clients have another format of message.
To send this message with normal encoding you should do this to subject:

```
$subject = "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode("Subject")."?=";// or any other encoding which you use at your site
mail("bat@mailservice.ru",$subject,"Message");
```

Also if the problem remains try adding header with encoding to your php page and in meta-tag:

php (before any echo):

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

html(at `<head>` of the page):

```
meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Also you can add this send header as aditional parameter of mail function.

```
$header="MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset='utf-8'";
mail("bat@mailservice.ru",$subject,"Message",$header);
```